# Updating a value in a Select based on a Greater Than clause

Tags: sql

I'm attempting to make a SQL report that would identify the current on hand quantity. The value listed in the select would display the given value in the table unless a rule is applied.

Essentially, I need assistance on how to write the IF statement.

```
SELECT itemno
    ,QOHQTY
    ,SAFETYSTOCKQTY
FROM EDI846OutboundDetail WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE PARTNERID = '987654321'
    AND itemno = '123465'`
```

This select would return

```
itemno  QOHQTY      SAFETYSTOCKQTY
123465  3.00000000  12.00000000
```

However, since `SAFETYSTOCKQTY` is greater than 3, then the select should return a ZERO in `QOHQTY`. If it is not, then it should continue to display 3 in `QOHQTY`.

I've been looking to use both an `IF` statement in a temp table, but I was trying to avoid that. Likewise, I discovered a `WHERE` CASE statement that may work, such as this *example* below.

```
SELECT '1'
FROM EDI846OutboundDetail WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE CASE WHEN SAFETYSTOCKQTY > 1 THEN '1'
END
    and PARTNERID = '987654321'
    AND itemno = '123465'
```

However, I was having troubles with how to format that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> since `SAFETYSTOCKQTY` is greater than `3`, then the select should return a ZERO in `QOHQTY`. If it is not, then it should continue to display 3 in `QOHQTY`.

Use `CASE`:

```
SELECT 
    itemno,
    CASE WHEN safetystockqty > 3 THEN 0 ELSE qohqty END qohqty,
    safetystockqty
FROM EDI846OutboundDetail WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE partnerid = '987654321' AND itemno = '123465'`
```

Or maybe, as commented by [averey_larry](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12055479/avery-larry), you want to compare `safetystockqty` against the value of `qohqty`? Then:

```
SELECT 
    itemno,
    CASE WHEN safetystockqty > qohqty THEN 0 ELSE qohqty END qohqty,
    safetystockqty
FROM EDI846OutboundDetail WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE partnerid = '987654321' AND itemno = '123465'`
```

Comment: I think it maybe should be case when safetystockqty > QOHQTY.

Comment: @avery_larry: ah yes, that would make more sense. I added that to my answer, thanks for your comment!

Comment: The second answer is ideal for my use case. That was an intended pun, but thank you to you both! Getting case statements to work was going to make me go crazy I thought today.